# How can I insert a given element in an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, insertion

[Here is the output to the code, the element actually gets inserted in the desired position but the initial value at that particular position in not translated to the next memory block, instead gets rewritten to the same value at the next block as seen in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQwt.png) So basically, I am not able to figure out how I could add an element at a given position provided user in a C array, of say integers. The array here is a one dimensional array.

I tried making an insertion function and put in my logic into code, the insertion takes place, but the issue it that when it happens, the pre - existing value at that position gets overwritten instead if just shifting to the right.

```
// code to insert a specific value in an already existing array at any user specified position

#include <stdio.h>
void creation(int size, int position, int value);
void insertion(int arr[], int size, int position, int value);

int main()
{
    int size, position, value;
    printf("Enter the size of the parent array you wish to create - ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    creation(size, position, value);
    return 0;
}

void creation(int size, int position, int value)
{
    int arr[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the parent array element - ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Parent array created with elements \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    insertion(arr, size, position, value);
}

void insertion(int arr[], int size, int position, int value)
{
    printf("Enter the position in the parent array where you would like to insert the element - ");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    if (position <= 0 || position > size+1)
    {
        printf("Invalid position entered, cannot add element! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the value you wish to insert - ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        for (int i = size-1; i >= position; i--)
        {
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];  // I THINK THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ARISING IN THE FINAL ITERATION OF THE LOOP, THE ARRAY BECOMES
                                // BECOMES EMPTY WHICH IS WHY THE VALUE IS GETTING REPEATED
        }
        arr[position-1] = value;
        size += 1;
        printf("Array after insertion successfully \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain this line `arr[position-1] = value;`

Comment: If you do `for (int i = size-1;` and then `arr[i+1]`, then i+1 is equal to `size` - probably one too far.

Comment: How did you *try* to debug this?

Comment: Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Aryan Mahawar You are using uninitialized variables position and value.

Comment: `int position, value;` both have indeterminate values, which are passed along to `creation` and then `insertion`, where both indeterminate values are overwritten by `scanf` (if it succeeds). These variables and the associated arguments are superfluous, and should simply be local to `insertion` (or otherwise be initialized externally, and remove the I/O from `insertion`).

Comment: `int arr[size];` is only large enough for the existing `size` values, but you want your `insertion()` function to insert one more value (keeping the existing `size` values). Therefore, it should be `int arr[size + 1];`.

Comment: @DavidJones I think OP is numbering positions from 1 rather than 0, hence `if (position <= 0 || position > size+1)`. But the array is currently too small by 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a bunch of issues with this.

First, you generate an array of size `size`.   In C, indexes are 0-based.  This means the valid indexes of the array would be `arr[0]` to `arr[size-1]`.   Specifically `arr[size]` is *not* valid, and attempting to write to it causes a memory scribble (i.e., it is *undefined behavior*).   This is important because you have the loop:

```
        for (int i = size-1; i >= position; i--)
        {
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
```

Notice on the first iteration, i=`size-1`, and thus you're assigning to `arr[size-1+1]` ==> (`arr[size]`).

Next, in the following lines:

```
        arr[position-1] = value;
        size += 1;
        printf("Array after insertion successfully \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", arr[i]);
        }
```

you increment size, but notice that this does *not* make the array bigger.   The space allocated for the array remains the same.   So now, when you do your for loop, you again loop to the new `size` - 1, which is one to far again.

As far as not inserting the value -- you would need to put some output of some sample data to show exactly what the issue you're facing is.

Finally, your loop should either go to `position - 1` (which is the 0-based index of the array)   So:

```
        //                v (note this is -2 here...)
        for (int i = size-2 ; i >= position-1; i--)
        {
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
```

or, even better:

```
        for (int i = size-1; i >= position; i--)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i-1];
        }
```

This moves the array element at the desired location

Comment: Thanks Henry! I have fixed the error pertaining to this code. for (int i = size-1; i >= position-1; i--) { arr[i+1] = arr[i]; } The mistake i did was here in the for loop, it should have been position-1, instead of just position

Answer (score 1):

A couple of additional suggestions as an addendum to [HardcoreHenry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77915506/15261315):

- You are using variables with indeterminate values when you pass `position` and `value` from `main` to `creation` and from there to `insertion`. As a result, code using these exhibits undefined behavior.
- You should use `size_t` as your type rather than `int` when interacting with positions in arrays. Make sure to use the printf format specifier `%zu` when printing such a value.
- You are not checking the `scanf` succeeded in reading a value. This is a very good habit to get into. It will return a value equal to the number of values read. If a valid `int` was not read in your case, you can try again. Be aware, though, that on an unsuccessful run, `scanf` leaves the invalid value in the stream to be read again.
- You should seek to keep functions as tightly focused as possible. A function that inserts a value into an array shouldn't need to do input and output. Decoupling the I/O from this makes it much easier to test your functions and verify they work as expected. Your `creation` function probably shouldn't be calling `insertion` either. Let `main` take care of that.
- You can replace your function moving values in the array with a single call to [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove).

So an `insertion` function might look like:

```
void insertion(int arr[], size_t size, size_t position, int value) {
    if (position >= size) return;

    memmove(
      &arr[position+1], 
      arr[position], 
      sizeof(int) * (size - position - 1)
    );

    arr[position] = value; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I have fixed the error pertaining to this code.                                               for (int i = size-1; i >= position-1; i--)
        {
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        }
The mistake i did was here in the for loop, it should have been position-1, instead of just position